# Is $0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z \xrightarrow{i_1} \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{\text{pr}_2} \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 $ a short exact seq?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

A friend od mine stated that

$0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z \xrightarrow{i_1} \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{\text{pr}_2} \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag{*} $

with $i_1$ the inclusion in the first component and $\text{pr}_2$ the projection in the second component,

was a short exact sequence (s.e.s). **Is this true?**

To begin with, I am not completely sure I understand what the elements of the direct sum are and how the inclusion works:

I guess $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\{(n,[0]), n \in \Bbb Z\}\cup \{(n,[1]),n \in \Bbb Z\}$

And what is the identity ? I guess it's $(0, [0])$

-Exactness at $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is clear because the projection is always surjective

-For exactness at $\Bbb Z$ we need $\{0\}$=$\text {Ker}(\text{i}_1)$.

-In order to have exactness at the direct sum term we need $\text {Im}(i_1)$=$\text {Ker}(\text{pr}_2)$.

$\text {Ker}(\text{pr}_2)=\{(n,[0]), n \in \Bbb Z\}$, because these are the elements that are map to [0] in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ right?

$\text {Im}(i_1)=?$ I am not sure how this inclusion works, if each integer $n$ is sent to both $(n,[0])$ and $(n,[1])$ that would not be a function.

**Could you help me clarify if my guesses are correct and what are then the correct  $\text {Ker}(\text{pr}_2)$ and $ \text {Im}(i_1)$ ?** This should answer whether $(*)$ is a short exact sequence or not

Comment: For any two modules $M$ and $N$, the sequence 
$$
0 \to M \to M \oplus N \to N \to 0, 
$$
with the first map $m \mapsto (m, 0)$ and the second map $(m, n) \mapsto n$, is always exact, *split* exact, in fact.

Comment: The "inclusion" map for $Z$ into the middle group is $n \mapsto (n, 0)$; it can't map to both $(n, 0)$ and $(n, 1)$, because then it wouldn't be a *function*. In general, inclusion of a factor $A$ into the direct sum $A \oplus B$ is defined by $a \mapsto (a, e_B)$, where $e_B$ is the identity element of $B$. (Any other choice for the second factor would make the inclusion map not be a homomorphism.)

Comment: @SammyBlack , Thanks I guess the answer is yes then. I ams still not very sure about the details of my particular proof. Is it correct that $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2 \cong \Bbb Z$?

Comment: Yes, you have a SES. I'm not sure where this supposed isomorphism in the comment comes from. Neither the inclusion nor projection in your problem setup is an isomorphism.

Comment: The inclusion is not surjective (it has a notrivial cokernel) and the projection is not injective (it has a nontrivial kernel).

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the [wiki page on split exact sequences](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Split_exact_sequence#Examples). From what you've written in the post and in the comments, it's difficult to figure out exactly what question remains.

Comment: @SammyBlack I am trying to determine if $(*)$  is an example of a s.e.s that when compared with $0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z \xrightarrow{\times 2} \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag{**} $, I have an isomorphism between every corresponding  set except for the ones in the middle. My friend stated so, by arguing that that $\Bbb Z \ncong \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$
 but I think the opposite, because I think we can identify $n$ with a $(n,[0])$

Comment: At the risk of this becoming a digressive conversation (you can post another question if you like!), the sequence above is *not* split, i.e. it's a different SES. The map $n \mapsto (n, 0)$ is an injective homomorphism, so it's an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ **onto its image**, but that image is not the entire target. In other words, you're identifying $\mathbb{Z}$ with a copy of itself living inside the larger $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, sometimes called an *embedding*.

Comment: But also, when you compare the two SESs, stacking one above the other, considering maps between corresponding groups, the lefthand square doesn't even commute with your proposed vertical map in the center.

Comment: @SammyBlack  I posted another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4791329/examples-of-pairs-of-short-exact-sequences-s-e-s-of-abelian-groups-with-all-bu I am not sure I need to satisfy commutativity of the diagram, but just as the question is stated there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it looks like the question was basically answered in the comments, I will write it down for the sake of the question not showing as unanswered.

For any two abelian groups (or modules) $A$ and $B$ sequence $$0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{i_A} A \oplus B \xrightarrow{p_B} B \rightarrow 0$$
is short exact with the maps being defined as $i_A(a) = (a,0)$ and $p_B(a,b) = b$.

To see this note that $(p_B\circ i_A)(a) = p_B(a,0) = 0$, so the composition is the zero map. Furthermore \begin{align}\ker p_B &= \{ (a,b)\in A\oplus B\mid p_B(a,b) = 0 \}\\ &= \{ (a,b)\in A\oplus B\mid b = 0 \} = \{ (a,0)\mid a\in A \} = \operatorname{im} i_A.\end{align} Exactness at $A$ and $B$ follows from injectivity of $i_A$ and surjectivity of $p_B$.

Let's answer your specific questions.

The direct sum you have is $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z = \{ (m,[n])\mid m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$ which you can write as disjoint union $\{(n,[0])\mid n \in \Bbb Z\}\cup \{(n,[1])\mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$ if you want.

Identity in any direct sum $A\oplus B$ is always given as $(0_A,0_B)$ where $0_A$ is the identity of $A$ and $0_B$ is the identity of $B$. This follows from definition of addition in $A\oplus B$ as $(a_1,b_1)+(a_2,b_2) = (a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2)$.

What you wrote before looking at the image of your map $i_1$ is all correct. Here you seem to be confused how $i_1$ is defined, it's simply $i_1(n) = (n,[0])$, elements $(n,[1])$ are not hit by $i_1$ for any $n$. Nor they need to be, $i_1$ doesn't need to be surjective (and won't be in general). Therefore, the image of your $i_1$ is $\{(n,[0])\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}$ which is exactly the kernel your wrote.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification just to be absolutely sure about a side thing from the comments, but important for me I would like to ask $\Bbb Z \ncong \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ correct?

Comment: @darkside, yes, they can't be isomorphic. $(0,[1])$ has order $2$ in $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ while $\mathbb Z$ doesn't have element of order $2$.