# Examples of pairs of short exact sequences (s.e.s) of abelian groups with all but one pairs of corresponding sets being isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

I am trying to find  examples of pairs of short exact sequences (s.e.s) of abelian groups:

$0\rightarrow M\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$ and

$0\rightarrow N\rightarrow N'\rightarrow N'' \rightarrow 0$

in the following cases

i) $M \cong N , M'\cong N' , M'' \ncong N''$;

ii)  $M \cong N , M'\ncong N' , M'' \cong N''$;

iii) $M \ncong N , M'\cong N' , M'' \cong N''$;

I have an example for the first one

i)
For any two $p$ and $q$ prime numbers, $p \neq q$:

$0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z \xrightarrow{\times p} \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag{**} $

$0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z \xrightarrow{\times q} \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag{**} $

They are clearly s.e.s and  $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z \ncong \Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z $

But I haven't been able to find any for the other two cases. Any help is appreciated. I would be nice to see other examples using other abelian groups as wel, the only one I could find in case i) was that one

**Edit:** Following the suggestion of lulu:

ii)

The groups of of order 4 that are not isomorphic are the cyclic group of order 4:$\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$  and the Klein 4-group $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Then, Would an  example for ii) be the following ?

$0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z   \rightarrow \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z   \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z  \rightarrow 0\tag 1$

$0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z   \rightarrow  \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag 2 $

I am not sure they are s.e.s though the quotient map $\Bbb Z \rightarrow  \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z $ is not injective

**Edit 2:** I am still trying to get a simpler example for iii) than that in the answer below

maybe this one works?

$0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z   \xrightarrow{i_2}  \Bbb Z  \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \xrightarrow{p_2} \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag 3 $

$0 \rightarrow 2\Bbb Z   \xrightarrow{i_1}  \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \xrightarrow{p_1} \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag 4 $

where $ i_j$ and $p_j$  ; j=1,2 are inclusion and projection maps in the corresponding components

Comment: For $ii$:  Hint:  there are two non-isomorphic groups of order $4$.

Comment: For $iii$:  Hint:  Consider $F: \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}\to \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ given by $(a)$ the identity and $(b)$ by the map $(a_1, a_2, \cdots)\mapsto ( a_2, a_3, \cdots)$. (N.B.  there is probably a more conventional example but this is the first one I thought of).

Comment: @lulu See my edit 2, will that work as an example of iii)?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about here.  I think you need to review the basics, groups and homomorphisms, before you start thinking about exact sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the comments:

For $ii$:  consider the two non-isomorphic groups of order $4$.  Thus we let $M_1'=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and let $M_2'=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.  Both of these admit surjections to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ with kernels also given by $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

For another famous example of $ii$ (which uses non-abelian groups) consider $$0\to \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\to  \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z \to  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 0$$ $$0\to \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\to S_3 \to  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\to 0$$

For $iii$ let $M'=N'$ both be the countably generated free abelian group $G=\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$.  For the first sequence we just consider the identity map from $G$ to itself, of course that has trivial kernel.  For the second we consider the map from $G$ to itself given by $(a_1, a_2, \cdots)\mapsto (a_2, a_3, \cdots)$.  That map is surjective, clearly, but the kernel is a copy of $\mathbb Z$.  Thus we have $$0\to <e>\to \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N} \to  \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}\to 0$$  and

$$0\to \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N} \to  \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}\to 0$$

Comment: See my edit, I guess I got (1) wrong

Comment: Right.  You need the arrow  $M'\to M''$ to be a surjection.  Clearly there is no surjection from $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: So it's $0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z   \rightarrow \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z   \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z  \rightarrow 0\tag 1$ Could you elaborate on why is $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z   \rightarrow \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z $ injective and  $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z   \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z $ surjective ? Not sure how the arrows are defined(what the functions are)

Comment: Well, just write everything out.  For the injection, we must have $0\mapsto 0$ of course, so just let $1\mapsto 2$. (Verify that this is a homomorphism).  Now you do the surjection.

Comment: Note:  I edited the post to include another example for $ii$, though this one has one non-abelian group in the mix.

Comment: Did you mean $1 \mapsto 1$ in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z $ Or could it be anything else like $1 \mapsto 1,2 $ or $3$? If it's $1 \mapsto 2$ the in this the multiplication by 2 map?

Comment: I am talking about the injection from $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.  Writing the first group additively as $\{0,1\}$ and the second additively as $\{0,1,2,3\}$ the injection $F$ is given by $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=2$.

Comment: Yes, I know, but isn't it more natural to have F(1)=1? Then I don't have to work to prove that it is an homomorphism, which is harder without the explicit formula of the map. And what prevents to have F(1)= 3 instead? Your choice suggest F(x)=2x, then that's an homom.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  if $F(1)=1$ then $0=F(0)=F(1+1)=F(1)+F(1)=1+1=2\neq 0$ so your $F$ is not a homomorphism.  Using my $F$, with $F(1)=2$, we get $0=F(0)=F(1+1)=F(1)+F(1)=2+2=0$ since $2+2=0$ in $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.  You should verify that taking $F(1)=3$ doesn't work either.

Comment: If $C_n$ denotes the cyclic group of order $n$, then to get an injection from $C_n\to C_m$  you need $C_m$ to have an element of order $n$.  Here, we just need $C_4$ to have an element of order $2$, which it clearly does.

Comment: I see I was thinking like :if it's the identity, then it should be a homom. because it does nothing. I think my error was that the class [1] is not the same in $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ and  $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$.  On the other hand the surjection  $G: \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ is then $G(0) =G(2)=0$ and $ G(1)=G(3)=1$ ? It takes a lot of time to be guessing what the definition is element-wise to get an isomorphism, isn't there a closed formula for G(x) that makes things faster? All I can find quickly is that 0 should map to 0.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  You really need to review the basics of group theory.

Comment: Could you please tell me who are M , N , M'' and N'' in iii)?

Comment: I put that in my post.  $M'=N'=G=\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}=M''=N''$.    $M=<e>$, the trivial group, and $N=\mathbb Z$.