# How should I define these maps to get short exact sequences?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

What should the correct definitions of $i_1, i_2, p_1$ and $p_2$ be to get short exact sequences with the given groups?

1. $0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z   \xrightarrow{i_2}  \Bbb Z  \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \xrightarrow{p_2} \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag 1 $
2. 

$0 \rightarrow 2\Bbb Z   \xrightarrow{i_1}  \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z \xrightarrow{p_1} \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \rightarrow 0 \tag 2 $

I would define them like this:

1)

$i_2(0)=(0,0); i_2(1)=(0,2)$

$p_2(n,0)=0; p_2(n,2)=0; p_2(n,1)=1; p_2(n,3)=1$

so I have exactness at the group in the center: $\text {ker}(p_2)=\{(0,m):  m\in\{0,2\} \subseteq \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\} = \text {Im}(i_2)$

2)

$i_1(2n)=(2n,0)$

$p_1(2n,m)=0; p_1(2n+1,m)=1$

so I have exactness at the group in the center
$\text {ker}(p_1)=\{(2n,m): n \in  \Bbb Z, m \in \Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\} = \text {Im}(i_1)$

**Is this correct? If not, why and how do i fix it?**

Comment: (1) cannot be made into a short exact squence; there is no definition of the maps that will do it. Note that the first (nontrivial) group is torsion, so it must map to the torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. That means that the quotient modulo the image will necessarily contain an element of infinite order; the quotient simply cannot equal $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, are you being purposefully confusing by labeling a sequence "1" and using the subscript $2$ for all its maps, and labeling a sequence "2" and using the subscript $1$ for all its maps, or was that very poor choice an accident?

Comment: Your choice for (2) cannot work. Remember that you must have the kernel of $p$ be equal to the image of $i$; since $(0,1)$ is not in the image of $i$, it cannot lie in the kernel of $p$, yet you explicitly put it in the kernel.

Comment: And please don't post multiple posts that are so closely related in short succession. [This is clearly about the same thing](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791315/742).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was using $i_2$ because it's a sort of inclusion into the second component and $p_2$ because is a sort of projection to the second component. Likewise with the other indices

Comment: So, purposefully confusing, then.